# Why do key inputs not work sometimes in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I make games using Flash CS5.5 with AS3 and when I use keys for input some keys, like the 'a' key, do not work at all. Also when certain keys are being pressed down other keys will be ignored. This is a problem with multiplayer games where lots of keys are being pressed at once. Does anyone know what causes this and how I can fix it?

Here is an example of the code I use for key inputs:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class BasicGame extends MovieClip {

    public var moveRight,moveLeft,moveDown,moveUp:Boolean;

    public function BasicGame() {
        stop();
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keysDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keysUp);
    }

    function keysDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode==70){
            moveRight=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==83){
            moveLeft=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==68){
            moveDown=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==69){
            moveUp=true;
        }
    }

    function keysUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
        if (e.keyCode==70){
            moveRight=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==83){
            moveLeft=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==68){
            moveDown=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==69){
            moveUp=false;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: This [is a keyboard hardware limitation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses). You can't rely on a lot of keys being pressed at the same time, even certain combinations of letters are not supported by keyboards while other combinations of the same number of keys but different letters are supported by the same keyboard.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as "ghosting." You want to look into an "anti-ghosting" keyboard which will allow multiple key presses at the same time